# RV without pdf but $P(X=x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Find a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ and a random variable $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(X=x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, while $X$ does not attain a probability density function.

Extra: does such an RV exit in every probability space?

Thanks a lot in advance!

(Some thoughts: I started with the Dirac measure $\delta_0$ (which does not attain a density function) on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$, but an RV that has the cdf $F$ attained by $\delta_0$ is the constant RV $X(\omega)=\min\{x: F(x)\geq \omega\}=0$, so $P(X=0)=1$, while $P(X=x)=0,~x\neq 0$).

Comment: I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution) works.

Comment: I expected it would be something nasty... Thanks @probablyme !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is actually an example for a random variable (or a distribution) which is continuous, but not absolutely continuous. One example for such a distributuon is the so-called Cantor distribution.

Note that, by the Radon-Nikodym theorem, a distribution $\mu$ is absolutely continous (with respect to the Lebesgue measure) if, and only if,

$$\mu(A)=0$$

for any (measurable) set $A$ with Lebesgue measure zero. If we assume that $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for all $x$, this yields $\mu(A) = 0$ for all countable sets $A$, but not necessarily $\mu(A) = 0$ for all Lebesgue-null sets.

Comment: does such an rv exist in every prob space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$? (the rv $X_C$ you suggested, if I am not mistaken, is defined on $([0,1], \mathcal{B},\lambda)$ as $X_C(\omega)=\min\{x:~F_C(x)\geq \omega\}$, where $F_C$ is the Cantor distribution ($\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure).

Comment: @NikolaosSkout Well, a random variable with a Cantor distribution exists on any probability space which is sufficiently rich (e.g. if there exists a sequence $(X_n)_n$ of independent Bernoulli distributed random variables). In general, however, we cannot expect that such a random variable exists because there are probability spaces on which we cannot find any random variable which is continuous (consider e.g. the case that $\Omega$ consists only of finitely many elements).