# Probability involving Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $A$ and $B$ be two Random Variables. If $A$ has a continuous CDF and $A$ and $B$ are independent, prove that :

$$ P(A - B = c) = 0 \ \forall c \in \mathbb{R} $$

I don't know how to proceed with this one.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has no context (and was asked and answered several times on the site, and asked at least once today).

Comment: Why the hurried acceptance? The only positive aspect of your approach, in a twisted way, is that if you give the "solution" below to your TA, she will probably skin you alive.

Comment: @Did lol. What exactly stands TA for, and what makes you so sure that it is a "she"?

Comment: @drhab TA = [Teaching Assistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_assistant). She : in the context, this is a [gender-neutral pronoun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28508/reason-for-the-current-trend-to-use-she-as-the-gender-neutral-pronoun).

Comment: @Did This makes clear to me that once I was a (G)TA myself. In Dutch: AiO (assistent in opleiding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c\in\mathbb{R}$ be fixed and let $\left[a-b=c\right]$ denote
the function $\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}$ that takes value $1$
is $a-b=c$ and takes value $0$ otherwise.

Then:

$$\begin{aligned}\mathsf{P\left(A-B=c\right)} & =\iint\left[a-b=c\right]dF_{A,B}\left(a,b\right)\\
 & =\iint\left[a-b=c\right]dF_{A}\left(a\right)dF_{B}\left(b\right)\\
 & =\int\mathsf{P}\left(A=b+c\right)dF_{B}\left(b\right)\\
 & =\int0dF_{B}\left(b\right)\\
 & =0
\end{aligned}
$$

The second equality applies independence of $A$ and $B$.

The fourth equality applies that $A$ has a continuous CDF.

Comment: Where are $da$ and $db$? What are $F_{A,B}$, $F_A$ and $F_B$?

Comment: @Did They are joint and individual cumulative distribution functions. One can integrate some function $h(x)$ on $F(x)$, and that would be equivalent to integrating $h(x)*f(x)$ on x for an absolutely continuous RV, and summing over $h(x)*f(x)$ for a discrete RV, and the summation of the two if the RV is mixture. This answer is more general than mine because it covers discrete, continuous or mixture distributions by not specifying their pdf's or pmf's. Also if B is singularly continuous, has something like a Cantor dbn, then $F_B$ will not be differentiable, hence need to stay as drhab gives it.

Comment: @FatihAkici Sorry but all this is much too careless ($F$ is not $dF$, simple integrals are not double integrals, etc.). At present the formulas in the post above make no sense, so I prefer to wait for the OP's corrections.

Comment: @Did My goodness I was careless too. You are absolutely right!

Comment: @Did I forgot the essential $d$ everywhere   and really don't understand how I could.... Thanks for attending.

Comment: @FatihAkici You asked in one of the comments under your deleted answer for an example of a continuous CDF that has no PDF. Such cases are rare but they do exist. See this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1675796/75923) for instance, and for an example see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution). If a distribution is said to be continuous then it cannot be concluded at once that a PDF exists. Existence of a PDF is expressed as: the distribution is "absolutely continuous". This means $P\ll\lambda$ where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.